Mockito inject some mock objects and some real objects
I'm testing a function like this:
public class CsvUtilsTest {
    @Mock
    private S3Client s3Client;
    @Mock
    private S3BucketWrapper s3Buckets;
    @Mock
    CsvMapper csvMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private CsvUtils csvUtils;
    ...

However, I do not want to mock the csvMapper (but instead inject a real one). I want to assert that certain outputs are correct and expand my tests to use the csvMapper as is, since it is third party. How can I do this?

If you don't want to mock csvMapper, then don't use the @Mock annotation on it and then use the @Before/setup() method (assuming JUnit 4) to create/obtain a real CsvMapper and assign it to csvMapper.

you can either use @Spy annotaton or you can manually instantiate the object to fulfil what you wanted to do.
you can use the @Spy annotation as per below syntax
 public class CsvUtilsTest {
        @Mock
        private S3Client s3Client;
        @Mock
        private S3BucketWrapper s3Buckets;
        @Spy
        private CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper(); 
    
        @InjectMocks
        private CsvUtils csvUtils;
}

Alternatively you can manually initialize the CsvMapper object in the set up method
public class CsvUtilsTest {
    @Mock
    private S3Client s3Client;
    @Mock
    private S3BucketWrapper s3Buckets;

    private CsvMapper csvMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private CsvUtils csvUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        csvMapper = new CsvMapper(); 
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    
}


Annotate csvMapper with @Spy instead of @Mock.
